# asp.net use membership provider to set role

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am building my first asp.net app from scratch. I have two different membership providers. One is a basic sql provider while the other is active directory. The user "role" is determined by how the user logs in. I want to use the Role Manager functionality of asp.net but I don't want to build the whole role provider part when I really don't have "roles" in my application, I have two membership types.

Is there a way to set the role of the user through the membership provider at login or in some way mark a logged in user as having been authenticated by sql or AD?

This is my first asp.net app, am I even thinking about this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roles and membership are two distinct things in asp.net.

On login you  need to assign a flag to the user object which identifies how they logged in.

Then in

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
```

check that flag and return an appropriate role

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on this?
What method is called that returns the user object?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the roles in a manner they aren't designed for, and I'm afraid you'll have to have a role-provider for it to work.

Why not use the MembershipUser.ProviderName property to check what provider provided the users identity?

Comment: How would I go about setting the providername property? I'm having difficulty even finding where the MembershipUser is created. If I could find that then I could programatically add a role at login, yes?

Comment: You stated that you are using two membershipproviders (sql and ad) so just call Membership.GetUser().ProviderName to check what provider the user came from. You won't need a roleprovider, but if you implement one you could add a role for the user. I don't know where to set this providername, I guess it can be done in the membership section of your web.config.